# Objects being retained by unreachable path in Chromium

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I have a JavaScript web app, and as I click around in it, the memory used by Chrome seems to creep up gradually over time.

I'm trying to trace what might be being retained, and I found a lot of a certain type of object (that was already one of my prime suspects for the leak).

The "heap snapshot" feature of Chromium looked like it might tell me what's actually retaining these objects, but it's being a bit unhelpful.

It looks like it's all hinging on one object that's being retained (and the others are all linked by parent/child lookups), but the thing that actually seems to be retaining it is not accessible:

[image: Screenshot of heap snapshot in Chromium]

I cleared the body (to eliminate retention by DOM elements) and removed the only global variable that referred to a `Context`, but I can't figure out why they're still hanging around.

Any idea what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Comment: a `Context` is an object that holds the free variables of a closure - unless you also have a normal constructor named `function Context(){}`

Comment: I have a normal constructor called `function Context() {...}`.  Closures are displayed as `system / Context`.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: The best memory leak tracking tool is Record Heap Allocation snapshot type in Chrome DevTool Profiler tab.